# Is it possible to remove brackets from single-line scopes using Auto-Reformat?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Is it possible to remove brackets from single-line scopes using Auto-Reformat ?

For example I have code like

```
if (i < -1)
{
    System.out.println("meh");
}
```

which Id like to become

```
if (i < -1)
    System.out.println("meh");
```

I'm using IDEA 13.

Comment: Also visit this [guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Intentions).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's pretty much possible. Open settings, navigate to "Code style → Scala" group, open "Wrapping and braces" tab and find "if() statements" item in the list of rules. Check that "Force braces" option is set to "Do not force". That way IDEA shouldn't add braces upon auto-reformat.

Comment: Thank you, Vladimir. I'd like to remove braces from existing code. The option you mentioned just prevents IDEA from adding braces to single-line scope.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that you meant *existing* code. I'm not aware of such option in IDEA, sorry.